# Windows Mobile 6 answer multiple calls

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, telephony, tapi

I develop a Windows Mobile 6 application where I have to manage multiple calls, using c++ TAPI (from C# using PInvoke).

The application works fine for a single call, but I do not know how to manage when I have an incoming call and I want to answer the second incoming call.

For example: I answer the first call with `lineAnswer`, I detect the second call and I want to accept it with `lineAccept`, then put the first call on hold `lineHold` and answer the second call with `lineAnswer`.

The problem is that I cannot manage at all the second call.
What steps (function calls) should I follow to manage 2 incoming calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution:

The command placed for the call is still `lineAnswer` but before, out application must be the owner of the call, so a I use `lineSetCallPrivilege` with the `Owner` value.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [OpenNetCF.Telephony](http://tapi.codeplex.com/) library? It's an open source C# wrapper around the TAPI functions, and it comes with a number of samples that show how to monitor and answer incoming calls. Maybe there are some pointers for you in there on how to handle your specific scenario.

Comment: I am currently using this library, but it provides me only lineAnswer option. I added myselt lineAccept but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What are you sending in the `lpsUserUserInfo` parameter of your lineAccept function?

Comment: I'm sending a NULL pointer. Do you thimk that it matters?  I shall make some more debugging to see what is the retirn code for lineAccept. Thanks.